# Highlighting selected text in html

Tags: html, highlight

I am trying to make a small tool that will allow the users to select and deselect text then save the selected text , then save it into a text file.

I tried the following:
http://jsbin.com/joqofojetu/1/

But I am stuck trying to unselect the text that was selected. Specially here:

```
  window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("highlighter").addEventListener(
    "mousedown",
    function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var addedElements = [];
      function nodeInserted(e) {
        var insertedNode = e.target;
        if (insertedNode.nodeType == 1) { // Element node
          addedElements.push(insertedNode);
        }
        console.log(e);
      }
      document.body.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", nodeInserted, false);
      highlight("yellow");
      document.body.removeEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", nodeInserted, false);

      addedElements.forEach(function(el) {
        document.getElementById("log").value += "Inserted " + el.tagName + " element with background colour " + window.getComputedStyle(el, null).backgroundColor + " and innerHTML " + el.innerHTML + "\n\n";
      });
    },
    false
  );
};
```

I tried other solutions as well but they always mess up when there is bold and italics elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do for small text and a single repetition

```js
function highlight(text) {
  var inputText = document.getElementById("inputText");
  var innerHTML = inputText.innerHTML;
  var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text);
  if (index >= 0) {
    innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0, index) + "<span class='highlight'>" + innerHTML.substring(index, index + text.length) + "</span>" + innerHTML.substring(index + text.length);
    inputText.innerHTML = innerHTML;
  }
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="highlight('fox')">Highlight</button>

<div id="inputText">
  The fox went over the fence
</div>
```